# Tree view visualization for very large amounts of Emails

Tags: file-management, email, imap

I have more than 10000 emails and I want to delete the ones I don't need anymore but it is too time consuming to go through them manually, so I am looking for a tree-view visualization of IMAP emails based on sender and the size of the messages including attachments should be the size of the box, alternatively the number of messages. Apart from just deleting all Emails from a specific sender there should also be the option to delete all attachments instead.

Something like what [Sequoia View](https://www.win.tue.nl/sequoiaview/) does for cleaning up full drives but for Emails would be perfect. Senders from the same domain could also be grouped in case it is a hierarchical visualization. And if one clicks into the box of a specific sender it should show all emails instead with those boxes scaled based on the size of that specific email.

Alternatively to group by sender, grouping by words or phrases in the subject would also be very useful, for example one could see that 10% of the space is used by emails with the phrase "mailing list" in them and delete all of them at once.